# Find the point-normal form for this line passing through point P

Tags: linear-algebra

Give the point-normal form for the following 2D line with the following description:
- Through ***P*(-2,5)** and perpendicular to the line **x + 2y = 5**

---

I know that the point-normal form is **n * (x - p) = 0**
when n is the normal vector, x = (x,y,z), and p is a point.

So, the point was given, therefore I get the following
**n * (x-(-2,5)) = 0**

but how do I find the normal vector?

---

Here's a picture of the exercise (#19)
[image]

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification. They're clearly asking for for a 2D line here, so the meaning of $n$ and $x$ are 2D points $(x, y)$ rather than 3D points $(x, y, z)$.

Comment: So the answer should be (1, 2) * (x - (-2, 5)) = 0  right?

Comment: No, that's not how you find the normal vector. I'm writing a full answer to this question right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, $p$ is a point on the line (in this case, $(-2, 5)$ works) and $n$ is the normal vector, but since this is a line in $\mathbb R_2$, $x$ is a 2D point that can be represented as $(x_1, y_1)$, **not** $(x_1, y_1, z_1)$.

Now, we are given that this line is perpendicular to $x+2y=5$. We can rewrite this as $x-0+2y-5=0$, which is the same as $1(x-0)+2(y-\frac 5 2)=0$. From this, we can notice that $(1, 2)$ is the normal vector of this line and $(0, \frac 5 2)$ is a point on this line because this line can be written as $(1, 2) \cdot (\mathbf x-(0, \frac 5 2))=0$. Thus, the normal vector for $x+2y=5$ is $(1, 2)$.

However, our line is *perpendicular* to this line, which means its normal vector is perpendicular to the normal vector of $(1, 2)$. To find the vector perpendicular to $(1, 2)$, we flip the coordinates of the vector and make the first coordinate negative to get $(-2, 1)$. If you take the dot product of $(1, 2)$ and $(-2, 1)$, you'll find that it comes out to $0$, showing that these two normal vectors are perpendicular. Thus, $(-2, 1)$ is the real normal vector of our line.

Now that we have the normal vector and a point on the line, we can write the line in point-normal form: $(-2, 1) \cdot (\mathbf x-(-2, 5))=0$.

Comment: Why is $x+2y=5$ rewritten as $x+0+2y−5=0$? Where did the zero come from? Would it not be $x+2y−5=0$?

Comment: 1. I just fixed some typos that did not change the overall answer. The equation is now $x-0+2y-5=0$.
2. I simply subtracted $0$ from the equation. Adding $0$ does not change the value of an expression. I added that $0$ to make it so I could factor out a $1$ from $x-0$ to get $1(x-0)$. I did something similar to $2y-5$ where I factored out a $2$ to get $2(y-\frac 5 2)$. This made it easy to see that $(0, \frac 5 2)$ was a point on the line and that $(1, 2)$ was the normal vector.

Comment: Ohh alright man, this actually makes sense now. It only took me 23 hours to understand :P

Comment: Glad I could help!